# What was the Publisher character trying to be a symbol of in "Mother!"?

Tags: character, analysis, mother

You may see the movie "Mother!". I've gotten confused about the symbolism of the *Publisher* character.

If we consider the writer as God, so his publishers would be the prophets because the prophets had the responsibility of broadcasting the messages of god to the world.

But the cruelty and violence  depicted by the character during the wartime in the movie, makes me confused. She even tried to kill the mother of nature, so she is a symbol of someone who tries to kill all the livings and destroy the nature! According to all the religions, prophets were not the cruel ones and they even tried to bring the peace and better ways to live to the people.

So my main questions are these:

1. If she stands for prophets why is she a negative character?
2. If she is not a prophet, then who is the publisher of god?
3. Does the character stand for followers of various religions who are always struggling with each other?

Comment: Try to limit it to one question per post instead of three. You'll have better luck. Also, it's policy.

Comment: @MeatTrademark They all seem to be quite interrelated and parts of the main question, though.

Comment: Interrelated, but still different enough in my opinion. I didn't VTC or downvote, but this seems to be pushing it. If/then questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Publisher, appears in the credits with the title of **Herald**.

The task of the Herald is to spread and filter (for his benefit) the literature of the poet (God) to all people, is the head of propaganda in charge of the crowd *buy* the message.

It is a key character to unleash the furor towards the poet.

We observe the Herald:

1. Bringing second editions (probably with differences from the original).
2. Taking control over the original manuscript.
3. Advertising the adoration of devotees toward the poet.
4. Worried about the *inspiration* of the poet.
5. Assassinating presumably heretics.

If we assume that the message is the bible, and more specifically, the new testament (*I thought you would not write again*, she says), then, we can conclude that **the Herald represents the political movement to formalize Christianity and its subsequent massification to the rest of the world**. .

Comment: This totally makes sense. In a more general POV,  we can refer it to any political movements,trying to formalize their religions. Tnx.